# ORA-29280 Oracle SQL developer error while trying to export table content as a csv

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, export-to-csv

```
create or replace procedure EXPORTTABLECONTENT is
    file_handle UTL_FILE.file_type;
begin
    file_handle := utl_file.fopen('CSV_DIR', 'csv.csv', 'w');
  for i in (
    select * from kwapp.minirules@ESDEV -- your query here
  ) loop
    utl_file.put_line(file_handle, 
      i.RULEINDEX || ',' || i.RULENAME
    );
  end loop;
  utl_file.fclose(file_handle);
end EXPORTTABLECONTENT;
```

I'm trying to export table content from minirules@ESDEV, but for some reason I get following error:

```
Connecting to the database EPS_ESDEV.
ORA-29280: invalid directory object
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 41
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 478
ORA-06512: at "AJ185194.EXPORTTABLECONTENT", line 4
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

Comment: Do you actually have access to the directory named 'CSV_DIR'?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use any directory name, but one of those that are available to you. See

```
SQL> select * from all_directories;

OWNER DIRECTORY_NAME  DIRECTORY_PATH
----- --------------- ---------------
SYS   EXT_DIR         c:\temp
```

Using your code (slightly modified so that it compiles in my database):

```
SQL> create or replace procedure exporttablecontent is
  2    file_handle utl_file.file_type;
  3  begin
  4    file_handle := utl_file.fopen('CSV_DIR', 'csv.csv', 'w');
  5
  6    for i in (select * from dept) loop
  7      utl_file.put_line(file_handle, i.deptno || ',' || i.dname);
  8    end loop;
  9    utl_file.fclose(file_handle);
 10  end exporttablecontent;
 11  /

Procedure created.

SQL> exec exporttablecontent;
BEGIN exporttablecontent; END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-29280: invalid directory path
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 41
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 478
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.EXPORTTABLECONTENT", line 4
ORA-06512: at line 1


SQL>
```

But, if I use directory which is available to me (i.e. `SYS` granted `read`/`write` privileges to me):

```
SQL> create or replace procedure exporttablecontent is
  2    file_handle utl_file.file_type;
  3  begin
  4    file_handle := utl_file.fopen('EXT_DIR', 'csv.csv', 'w');       --> here
  5
  6    for i in (select * from dept) loop
  7      utl_file.put_line(file_handle, i.deptno || ',' || i.dname);
  8    end loop;
  9    utl_file.fclose(file_handle);
 10  end exporttablecontent;
 11  /

Procedure created.

SQL> exec exporttablecontent;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

It *works* (as expected).

---

How does `SYS` grant privileges on a directory? Like this:

```
SQL> connect sys as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> grant read, write on directory ext_dir to scott;

Grant succeeded.

SQL>
```